# How to detect if inner text of div element changes and then record date / time of

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below which appears to be close, *but still isn't printing in consol.log test*. So, still not exactly. I want to continuously detect if my div element's content has **changed** *(via inner text of elem)*, record the inner `text` and `date` / `time` of change, and also the document `referrer` when this happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var element = document.querySelector('.pet-name'); 

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName = 'data-pet-name') {

      var petname = $('.pet-name').text();
      var referrer = document.referrer;

      var date = new Date();
      var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      var day = date.getUTCDate();
      var year = date.getUTCFullYear();

      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;

            console.log(referrer); 
            console.log(petname); 
            console.log(time); 
            console.log(formattedDate); 
    }
  });
});

var config = { // some kind of attempt
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['pet-user-name']
};

observer.observe(element, config);

setTimeout(function() { // this is just for testing purposes of change elem
    $('.pet-name').text('Huge Fat Cat');
}, 6500);

});
```

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rcf8cm7z/2/). Cheerio.

Comment: The first `if` statement in your observer looks suspicious - should that `=` be `==` or `===`? (That is, a comparison instead of an assignment?)

Comment: Also, your code seems to be looking for a change to the "data-pet-name" attribute, but what your timeout code does is change the text content of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that your `if` condition is never being met because you are not comparing, you are assigning. Without it, the code runs as expected. So, you need to correct that.

```js
$(function() {

var element = document.querySelector('.pet-name'); 

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      var petname = $('.pet-name').text();
      var referrer = document.referrer;

      var date = new Date();
      var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      var day = date.getUTCDate();
      var year = date.getUTCFullYear();

      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
      
   console.log(referrer); 
   console.log(petname); 
   console.log(time); 
   console.log(formattedDate);   
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(element, config);
 

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.pet-name').text('Huge Fat Cat');
}, 1000);


     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pet-name">
Big Fat Dog
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quality answer, scott marcus!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!